# Construct file path using shell parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell, brace-expansion

I need to construct an absolute file path based on the values of two variables in bash. I have the following two variables:

```
MY_FILE_NAME=myfile-1.0.0.80234.txt ### This variable is NOT guaranteed to be set
WORKING_DIR=/var/my_working_dir     ### This variable is guaranteed to be set
MY_PATH=<Some parameter expansion magic>
```

If the variable MY_FILE_NAME is set then MY_PATH should have the value:

```
/var/my_working_dir/myfile-1.0.0.80234.txt
```

If the variable MY_FILE_NAME is not set then MY_PATH should be same as value of WORKING_DIR. How do I achieve this using parameter expansion preferably in just one line.

Comment: If you don't mind a trailing `/` then simple **`MY_PATH="$WORKING_DIR/$MY_FILE_NAME"`** will also work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work for you:

```
[[ $MY_FILE_NAME ]] && MY_PATH="$WORKING_DIR/$MY_FILE_NAME" || MY_PATH="$WORKING_DIR"
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I realized I posted a stupid question when I first saw your comment. It's fine if extra trailing slashes get added.

Comment: Ah in that case you just needed `MY_PATH="$WORKING_DIR/$MY_FILE_NAME"`

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
MY_PATH=${WORKING_DIR}${MY_FILE_NAME:+/}${MY_FILE_NAME:-}
```

Comment: This will add an extra `/` in the end and OP wrote `If the variable MY_FILE_NAME is not set then MY_PATH should be same as value of WORKING_DIR.`

Comment: Thanks, I think it be simplified to: `MY_PATH=${WORKING_DIR}${MY_FILE_NAME:+/}${MY_FILE_NAME}`